# Agilent 4294A Impedance Analyzer: "Bridge Unbalanced" during calibration

Tags: impedance, measurement, calibration, lcr

I am having problems calibrating my test fixture for the Agilent 4294A Impedance Analyzer. The open measurement always works, but with the short measurement I always get the error message "Bridge Unbalanced".

The same problem was described a few years ago (https://community.keysight.com/thread/4715), but never answered.

I changed all parameters like amplitude, frequency, bandwidth etc., but without success. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is or what you could do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. There was a broken fuse on the DC power source board A4. I renewed it (just a few cents) and now the device is working again.

Comment: Excellent hint, thank you!
Replacing the fuse cured our 4294A too that showed the "unbalanced bridge" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's going to be an invalid setup/value for the short compensation.

Take a look at [this](https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=1948434&nid=-33831.0.00&id=1948434) answer at Keysight.